# 404 page doesn't get data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, handler

I have a problem with data in 404 page.

Handler.php

```
   public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
            $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();
            switch ($statusCode) {
                case '404':
                    $obj = new \App\Http\Controllers\SiteController(new \App\Repositories\CatalogsRepository(new \App\Catalog));
                    $obj->template = env('THEME') . '.404';
                    return response($obj->renderOutput());
            }
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

RenderOutput in SiteController

```
public function RenderOutput()
    {
        $catalogItems = $this->getCatalogs();
        $cart_info = $this->CartInfo();
        $menu = view(env('THEME') . '.menu')->with(['catalogs' => $catalogItems, 'cart_info' => $cart_info,'title'=>$this->title])->render();
        $this->vars = array_add($this->vars, 'cart_info', $cart_info);
        $this->vars = array_add($this->vars, 'menu', $menu);

        return view($this->template)->with($this->vars);
    }
```

When Im logged, in regular pages I have links like log out, my orders, personal info, etc.. and if cart has items it shows its amount and qty of items, but when 404 shows up, its like im not logged in (have register and login links) and have 0 items with 0 qty in cart. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's **only** because **Laravel** starts the `session` if the **route** was matched:

in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` try to add this to your **$middleware** :

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
```

Comment: Thank you alot! Worked like a charm ;)

Comment: this will cause issues with data sharing through sessions, example : `session::get('errors');` will be empty, if you don't remove it from $middlewareGroups, so make sure to move it and not have duplicate StartSessions